# C# How To Achieve Monitor.Enter/Exit With Task Based Async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, locking

This is my code that works. I wouldn't have to do this if it weren't task based async, but using Monitor.Enter/Exit results in this problem [Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code. Exception on Mutex.Release()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017521/object-synchronization-method-was-called-from-an-unsynchronized-block-of-code-e)

People have mentioned using AutoResetEvent, and SemaphoreSlim, but I'm not quite sure which pattern fits.

```
private bool fakelock;

internal async Task<byte[][]> ExchangeCore(byte[][] apdus)
{
    if (apdus == null || apdus.Length == 0)
        return null;
    List<byte[]> resultList = new List<byte[]>();
    var lastAPDU = apdus.Last();

    while (fakelock)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    fakelock = true;

    foreach (var apdu in apdus)
    {
        await WriteAsync(apdu);
        var result = await ReadAsync();
        resultList.Add(result);
    }

    fakelock = false;

    return resultList.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use a SemaphoreSlim which supports async.

```
private static SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

internal async Task<byte[][]> ExchangeCore(byte[][] apdus)
{
    if (apdus == null || apdus.Length == 0)
        return null;

    await Semaphore.WaitAsync();

    try
    {
        List<byte[]> resultList = new List<byte[]>();
        foreach (var apdu in apdus)
        {
            await WriteAsync(apdu);
            var result = await ReadAsync();
            resultList.Add(result);
        }
        return resultList.ToArray();
    }
    finally
    {
        Semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dying to test this! I have a gut feeling that SemaphoreSlim in the correct approach, I just didn't have a working example for this pattern, but now I do. Thanks.

Comment: Your code made it in to this class: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/ledger-dotnet-api/blob/master/LedgerWallet/Transports/HIDTransportBase.cs which has been submitted as a pull request to the parent repo.