# Mutex/Monitor not working for C# Thread synchronization

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to only allow one `Thread` to access a non-static method from an `object`. I don't really create Threads but use Tasks instead. I tried to lock the method down to one usage but it just isn't working, I first tried it with a static `Mutex` object, then a non-static `Mutex` object but even with a simple monitor it's not working.

My code:

```
private async void LoadLinkPreview()
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: FEHLERTRÄCHTIG!
            Monitor.Enter(_loadLinkMonitor);
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Entered LinkPreview");

            // Code ...
            // There are also "await" usages here, don't know if this matters
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
             Monitor.Exit(_loadLinkMonitor);
             Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Left LinkPreview");
        }
    }
```

and this is what the Console displays:

```
3/12/2013 6:10:03 PM: Entered LinkPreview
3/12/2013 6:10:05 PM: Entered LinkPreview
3/12/2013 6:10:05 PM: Left LinkPreview
3/12/2013 6:10:06 PM: Left LinkPreview
```

Of course sometimes it works in the wanted order but I want it to always work. Can someone help me maybe?

EDIT: I realized that the console display could be wanted behavior, since the "Left" `WriteLine()` is after the monitor has been exited, but I switched them now and can confirm that there are definitely two threads working at the same time! Also a more obvious console result:

```
3/12/2013 6:26:15 PM: Entered LinkPreview
3/12/2013 6:26:15 PM: Entered LinkPreview
2 had an error! // Every time the method is used I count up now, this confirms that the second
// time the method is called the error is produced, which would not happen if the monitor
// is working because I have an if statement right upfront ...
3/12/2013 6:26:17 PM: Left LinkPreview
3/12/2013 6:26:18 PM: Left LinkPreview
```

Comment: That inner await probably matters. Not sure if it applies to a monitor, but if a thread tried to lock() something twice (nested), it is allowed to do so without being blocked. You would get the behavior you noted.

Comment: (If the *same* thread tries to lock something twice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually possible that your code *is* working as intended, and your problem is just with the display.

The issue is here:

```
 Monitor.Exit(_loadLinkMonitor);
 Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Left LinkPreview");
```

You write out the timestamp *after* you exit the monitor.  Keep in mind that the other code that is waiting to enter the monitor can start executing as soon as `Exit` is called.  So it's possible for the current thread to call exit, then before the `Debug` call, the other thread can `Enter` the monitor and write it's on "Entered" line.

If you change the code to:

```
 Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Left LinkPreview");
 Monitor.Exit(_loadLinkMonitor);
```

Then it won't change the behavior, but you'll remove the logging bug.  If it's *still* out of order, then you do indeed have a problem somewhere in your code.

On a side note, if you have an `async` method you should avoid calling methods that do a blocking wait, such as `Monitor.Enter`.  If you use `SemaphoreSlim` you can use it's `WaitAsync` method to ensure that the method doesn't block.  That would look something like this:

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
private async void LoadLinkPreview()
{
    try
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Entered LinkPreview");
        await Task.Delay(2000);//placeholder for real work/IO
    }
    finally
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Left LinkPreview");
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I edited my answer already I saw that there was something unclear =) I will try the SemaphoreSlim, it sounds great, but it should work anyways or not?

Comment: @Smirnoff4u The second half, referring to using a `SemaphoreSlim` is not related to your problem, it's just an improvement of your code.  The problem is what I discuss at the start; the ordering of your logging vs your locking operations.

Comment: Yes, but I switched them now and it still doesn't work, so that wasn't the issue.

Comment: @Smirnoff4u Then it's probably related to code that you haven't shown.

Comment: SemaphoreSlim works beautifully! Thank you very much, I think this also explains issues I had in other applications! A follow up question:

If I need a mutex for process synchronization, would something like this be fine? 

public async static void F()
{
await _semaSlim.WaitAsync();
await DoMutexWork();
_semaSlim.Release();
}

private static void MutexWork()
{
Mutex.WaitOne()
// Storage stuff
Mutex.ReleaseOne()
}

Comment: @Smirnoff4u I would think so.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: ditched all of that.  Here's the answer: [Why can't I use the 'await' operator within the body of a lock statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement)

You aren't supposed to do what you're trying to do, using "await" inside of essentially a "lock" statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use standard multithreading primitives such as `Monitor` in an `async` method. The C# compiler will stop you if you use a `lock` statement, but if you do it "manually" via `Monitor.Enter` then you will just end up shooting yourself in the foot.

If you think about it for a bit, it makes perfect sense. What happens when an `async` method yields? It *returns* an uncompleted `Task` and *allows other code to run* while it's (a)waiting. That totally goes against the point of a lock, which is to *prevent other code from running* while the lock is held. There are also situations (such as an ASP.NET or thread pool context) where the `async` method resumes on a different thread; in this case, one thread takes a lock and another thread releases it. Insanity! Cats and dogs living together!

The built-in .NET solution is `SemaphoreSlim`, which works as a lock/semaphore (though it does not have built-in `IDisposable` for use with `using`). Stephen Toub wrote a blog series on [`async` coordination primitives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx), and I have a [full suite implemented in my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/documentation), available via NuGet.