# WP8 Mutex - Resource Locking

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm having issues understanding the Mutex class and how to properly use it in a WP8 application. What I'm attempting to do is allow only a ScheduledAgent or the application to read/write a file to storage at a time. I've tried this various ways with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

ScheduledAgent code:

Below code errors out when I call ReleaseMutex(). This issue is fixed when I create the Mutex object like so: new Mutex(**true**, "FlightPathData"). But then I can never get a lock and hangs on WaitOne()

Error

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Code

```
readonly Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "FlightPathData");

protected async override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
      List<METAR> savedMetars = null;
      var facility = ....;

      bool mutexAcquired = mutex.WaitOne();
      try
      {
           if (mutexAcquired)
           {
               savedMetars = await Data.LoadMetarsAsync(facility.Identifier);
               //Thread.Sleep(15000);
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           if (mutexAcquired)
           {
               mutex.ReleaseMutex();
           }
       }

       NotifyComplete();
 }
```

ViewModelCode (Works fine till the ScheduledAgent ReleaseMutex() fails)

```
static readonly Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "FlightPathData");
...
mutex.WaitOne();
var savedMetars = await Data.LoadMetarsAsync(this.Facility.Identifier);
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

Comment: It appears this line: savedMetars = await Data.LoadMetarsAsync(facility.Identifier); Causes the task to enter another thread since it's async and when it tries to release the Mutex it can't. I comment out that code and everything works as it should...very odd.

Comment: @Stehen: Could you please elaborate a little about "you can't use a mutex with async code"? In my UWP apps I need to synchronize resource access (e.g. to storage files) between the foreground app and its background tasks (living in separate processes). In my [tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843812/how-to-synchronize-resource-access-between-uwp-app-and-its-background-tasks) mutexes seem to work fine (which I know is no prove).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use thread-affine locks with `async` code. This is because the `await` can cause the method to return (while holding the mutex) and then another thread can continue the `async` method and attempt to release a mutex it does not own. If this is confusing, I have an [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

So you can't use `Mutex` or other thread-affine locks such as `lock`. However, you can use [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). In your `async` methods, you would use `await WaitAsync` instead of `Wait`.

Comment: I actually just got done reading an article on async / await and was about to post what you just stated. I did not know about SemaphoreSlim and will do some reading up on that for sure. That being said, I just ended up creating additional methods that write synchronously to IsolatedStorage and that indeed did fix the issue. Appreciate the post and links!

Comment: @Stehen: Could you please elaborate a little about "you can't use a mutex with async code"? In my UWP apps I need to synchronize resource access (e.g. to storage files) between the foreground app and its background tasks (living in separate processes). In my tests mutexes seem to work fine (which I know is no prove).

Comment: @PeterMeinl: Mutexes are thread-affine, so they don't work with async code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement