# How to synchronize resource access between UWP app and its background tasks?

Tags: win-universal-app

In WP7 apps I use a named Mutex to synchronize access to StorageFiles and Tiles.
With the async code of UWP apps this is no longer robust because mutexes are thread-affine and mixed with async code this results in errors "*Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code*".

```vb
Using mutex As New Threading.Mutex(False, "SyncAppAndBackTask")
    Try
        Await ...
    Finally
        mutex.ReleaseMutex()
    End Try
End Using
```

Using a SemaphoreSlim is not a option here because app and background tasks run in different processes.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118177/is-there-anything-wrong-with-await-task-run-semaphore-waitone/23122566#23122566) suggests using Taks.Factory.StartNew with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning or a StaTaskScheduler.

LongRunning does not solve the problem as my test code proves, see [here](http://1drv.ms/1nr4u1W).
The versions of StaTaskScheduler I found use the Thread class which is not available in UWP.

Does someone have a solution for this or at least a UWP compatible version of StaTaskScheduler - in the post above Noseratio mentions "new Thread" could be replaced using Factory.StartNew.

As a workaround I currently use a storage file lock via .OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite) but this leads to ugly retry-loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new **Single Process Model** of the Anniversary SDK syncing became much easier because background processing no longer runs in a different process. I am using the AsyncLock from Stephen Clearey's AsyncEx with it.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Statements like *"Mutexes are thread-affine, so they don't work with async code"* and bugs in my apps and tests had made me suspicious that we generally cannot use a named Mutex to synchronize resource access between an UWP app and its background tasks. All alternative solutions I saw only work in-process.

I came to the conclusion that mutexes do work fine in this scenario as long as .ReleaseMutex is coded on the same level as .WaitOne (e.g. not within an async method awaited after .WaitOne).

For coding convenience I encapsulated the mutex handling to allow Using statements:

```
'Usage to serialize access:
Using New AppAndBackgroundMutex(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    'Access storage files
    'Access ApplicationData settings
    'Update Tiles
End Using

'Usage to back out:
Using New AppAndBackgroundMutex(TimeSpan.Zero)
    '...
End Using

Public NotInheritable Class AppAndBackgroundMutex : Implements IDisposable
    Private _mutex As Threading.Mutex
    Private _iOwnMutex As Boolean
    Sub New(waitTimeout As TimeSpan, Optional syncId As String = "SyncRates&Selections&Date")
        Const UniqePartOfMutexName = "<app specific GUID>"
        Try
            _mutex = New Threading.Mutex(False, UniqePartOfMutexName & syncId)
            _iOwnMutex = _mutex.WaitOne(waitTimeout)
            If Not _iOwnMutex Then
                Dim msg = ($"Unable to acquire mutex for app/background sync after waiting for {waitTimeout}.")
                If waitTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero Then
                    'Intentionally backing out
                    Trace.Info(msg)
                Else
                    Trace.Error(msg)
                End If
                Throw New MutexTimeoutException(msg)
            End If
        Catch ex As Threading.AbandonedMutexException
            Trace.Error("Abandoned Mutex detected! OS might have killed background task. Ignoring problem.")
            _iOwnMutex = True
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Simple Dispose implementaion because class is sealed
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        If _iOwnMutex Then _mutex.ReleaseMutex()
        _ mutex.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Alternatively one could use a file lock to back out:

```
Try
    Dim file = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("__AppAndBackgroundSync.lock", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
    Await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)
    '...
Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
    Throw New AppAndBackgroundConcurrencyViolationException()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for and async lock. Take a look at http://asynclock.codeplex.com.

Comment: No, I thought there was a general problem using a named mutex with async code. Your link does look interesting though. However these async locks do not seem be intended for x-process scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception, because you are not blocking the thread with *mutex.WaitOne()*, thus your mutex is not signaled and therefore your code is unsynchronized and you get exception:

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code

Try it like this:

```vb
Async Function TestMutex() As Task
    Using mutex As New Threading.Mutex(False, "SyncAppAndBackTask")
        Try
            mutex.WaitOne()
            For i = 1 To 3
                Await SimulateCompute()
                Debug.WriteLine(i)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Throw
        Finally
            mutex.ReleaseMutex()
            Debug.WriteLine("success")
        End Try
    End Using
End Function
```

Also in your code you seem to be using *TaskCountinuationOtions*, whether in *StartNew* it should be *TaskCreationOptions*. Though, both are enums and *LongRunning* equal 2.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and fixing my code. Omitting mutex.WaitOne() only happened when shortening my production code for the test sample. With this fix my test no longer produces the exception mentioned.

Comment: Now I can no longer reproduce the exception. Simply using the mutex without any additional measures seems to work fine. I saw you posted a similar question
[Named Mutex with await](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153155/named-mutex-with-await)
and settled for a solution based on a custom TaskScheduler. I am no longer shure a problem synchronizing async file IO with a named mutex exists. What do you think?

Comment: @PeterMeinl In UWP direct thread managing is not possible, therefore I'm not sure now, how the solution with custom TaskScheduler would look like. Though, as I think, the *LongRunning* task should work - it dedicates single thread for a task and after returning from await it should be possible to safely release mutex. If your async operation is not long you may also consider synchronous waiting instead of awaiting after acquiring mutex. The best would be just to test it - maybe create a sample BTask, open a file and to the same in main UI (both with global mutex).

Comment: My current App does synchronizes the UI with a BackTask using a named mutex and seems to work fine. As a precaution it traces mutex .WaitOne(_preventHangingTimespan) timeouts and .ReleaseMutex exceptions and reports them via ApplicationInsights. But Stephen Cleary writes in 
[WP8 Mutex - Resource Locking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876081/wp8-mutex-resource-locking)
"You can't use thread-affine locks with async code" and this makes me wonder if I missed something.

Comment: @PeterMeinl The best would be to ask Stephen Cleary :) - maybe you can ensure if you can combine LongRunning task with mutex and awiat. IMO you can mix await and mutex, but you have to ensure that the same thread acquires and releases the mutex.

Comment: @PeterMeinl do we really need to `Await SimulateCompute()` in a background task that has no UI thread ? I faced the same problem as you today and I ended up using `SimulateCompute().Wait()` in order for the `ReleaseMutex()` code that follows it to work and not throw an exception.

Comment: @user3185569: If you can solve the problem by avoiding mixing with async code that is fine. But often this is not possible or sprinkled in .Waits cause deadlocks. The solution of my answer is not as robust as I would like. Sadly neither Microsoft nor one of the people with deep understanding of async offered practical advice. BTW: using .Wait encapsulates Exceptions in AggregateExceptions, so often it might better to use GetAwaiter().GetResult().