# Skip SemaphoreSlim instead of wait

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

I have a part of code in an Async/Await function that I only want one thread to execute at a time.

This is relatively simple by creating a new SemaphoreSlim(1) and using WaitAsync/Release. The effect is that the first thread executes while the others wait and then execute one by one.

What I am trying to achieve is actually slightly different. I would like the other threads not to wait, but to return out of the function (i.e. I don't want to block the other threads). So if there was a property "NumberOfThreadsCurrentlyExecuting" I would effectively have an If Semaphore.NumberOfThreadsCurrentlyExecuting > 0 Then Return.

But such a property doesn't exist. Does anyone have any idea for a way around this problem?

Thanks
Charles

Comment: Check [CurrentCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.currentcount.aspx)?

Comment: Right. Stupid question. Sorry! I understood CurrentCount was refering to the maximum number of threads not the remaining.

Comment: and realising where my mistake comes from: the tooltip in VS for CurrentCount says "Gets the number of threads that will be allowed to enter the System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim", which is ambiguous (and I interpreted as maximum).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Instead of a Semaphore, you could just use a `Monitor`.

If you call [`TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw(v=vs.110).aspx) and it fails, another thread is in the "lock".

This is thread safe (unlike checking semaphore counts), and fairly simple:

// using somethign like: object sync = new object();

```
bool lockTaken = Monitor.TryEnter(sync);
try
{
  if (lockTaken) 
  {
      // You're here - do your work
  }
  else
  {
      // Something else was in the thread - exit?
      return;
  }
}
finally
{
   if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(sync);
}
```

Comment: thanks. That's a good way too! Does it work well with async/await? Await is not allowed within a SyncLock and I would have thought this seems pretty close to a lock.

Comment: @Charles It works, but it's very dangerous - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7612714/65358

Comment: That was my concern. I assumed that because SemaphoreSlim has an Async WaitAsync method it is safe to place some await calls between the WaitAsync/Release but do you think there is a similar risk?

Comment: @Charles Anything that's giving you blocking semantics has the same issue if you try to await within it... Read that post ;)

Comment: For now I have to downvote this -- the question talks about async/await, and this will not really work right for async/await (as you point out)

Comment: @MarkSowul The exact same issue occurs with any synchronization primitive (including SemaphoreSlim) - it's not a matter of which class you use, but the way async/await works.  It can work, but it's dangerous - but the same exact issues occur with your solution.

Comment: Deadlocks, yes; thread re-entrancy, no.  (Enter the lock on one thread, await, continue on another thread; or, another await continues on your thread after you've entered the lock and awaited)

Comment: Enters every time for me, because my async method is called from the Dispatcher-Thread every time!

Answer (score 39):

How about using the `SemaphoreSlim.Wait/Async` with a zero-timeout?  If it can't enter the semaphore (because it's already been entered), it will return false.

### Note that `Monitor` (and thus `lock`) is completely unsuited to `async`

(hence the fact that you can't `await` in a `lock`) because

1. your task may continue on another thread after you've entered the lock (thus you will try to release the lock from another thread)
2. after you've awaited, another continuation may use your thread (while it is still holding the lock), so if it attempts to acquire the lock it will succeed

Comment: The Zero Timeout was what I needed! I want my method to exit immediately if it can't aquire the lock/event/whatever...

Comment: In other words: don't use `await` inside lock/monitor. Thanks for the `Wait(0)` tip!