# Is it possible to await task completion on different threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

What I mean is, say we have an async method `Task<string> CalculateSha256(string s)`. Is it possible, that calls from thread #1 and thread #2 are executed **consecutively** as oposed to being executed concurrently, without threads #1 and #2 knowing anything about each other? For example, I have a controller,

```
public async Task<string> Get(string value)
{
    return await CalculateSha256(value);
}
```

and I want two different requests to access the chunk of code that's responsible for calculation (CalculateSha256) consecutively.

Comment: this is a different question, because these two threads should not await the **same** task, however, one should wait for the end of another, in order to continue.

Comment: Can you show what you're trying to achieve? Perhaps Task's `ContinueWith()` may be an answer? Or `TaskCompletionSource` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to synchronize the access to CalculateSha256 method that only one thread will execute it at a time.
Since `lock` statement [does not play nicely with async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement) you can use [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Just add it as a static field to your controller:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

And use [WaitAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462805(v=vs.110).aspx) method in your action (and do not forget to release it when you finish, using finally block):

```
public async Task<string> Get(string value)
{
    await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        return await CalculateSha256(value);
    }
    finally
    { 
        _semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

If you find this approach useful and you do not like to reapeat the try finally block you can create a base controller class with a protected generic helper:

```
protected async Task<T> GetConsecutively(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory)
{
    await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        return await taskFactory();
    }
    finally
    { 
        _semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

And modify Get method to pass a lambda expression to it:

```
public async Task<string> Get(string value)
{
    return await GetConsecutively(() => CalculateSha256(value));
}
```

Or alternatively use Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock) instead of `SemaphoreSlim` which supports a high level API closer to the `lock` statement:

```
private static readonly AsyncLock _asyncLock = new AsyncLock();

public async Task<string> Get(string value)
{
    //Notice the use of using block
    //instead of try and finally 
    using(await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
    {
        return await CalculateSha256(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you generalize your answer so that it can work for any `Task<T>` , you can get more upvotes in future

Comment: @L.B Thanks for the tip, please refer my edit :)