# Lock and SemaphoreSlim usage difference with async/await

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, locking

When accessing critical section in C# with async/await keywords, using **lock** keyword or **Monitor** is generally not advised ([Why can't I use the 'await' operator within the body of a lock statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement)), because it introduces deadlock in the situation where thread that locked critical section section will possibly be not avaliable.

The general approach is to use `SemaphoreSlim` class.

My question is that since `SemaphoreSlim(1,1)` and lock are functionally the same, what is the reason that it's okay to use one, but the other introduces deadlock?

Is it because SemaphoreSlim can be released from any thread, while lock is "owned" exclusively by the thread that locked it?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it because `SemaphoreSlim` can be released from any thread, while `lock` is "owned" exclusively by the thread that locked it?

Yes, this is the reason. The `lock` is thread-affine, while the `SemaphoreSlim` is not. The `SemaphoreSlim` doesn't care which thread releases it. On the contrary the `lock` would throw a [`SynchronizationLockException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationlockexception) if somehow you managed to switch to another thread before exiting the `lock`. Which you can't, because the C# language doesn't allow an `await` inside a `lock`.