# What are the advantages of using `lock` over `SemaphoreSlim`?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, semaphore

I'm late to the party, but I recently learned about [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-7.0):

I used to use [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) for synchronous locking, and a `busy` boolean for asynchronous locking.  Now I just use `SemaphoreSlim` for everything.

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

private void DoStuff()
{
    semaphoreSlim.Wait();
    try
    {
        DoBlockingStuff();
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

vs

```
private object locker = new object();

private void DoStuff()
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        DoBlockingStuff();
    }
}
```

Are there any synchronous cases where I should prefer using `lock` over `SemaphoreSlim`?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are the advantages of the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) over the [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim):

1. The `lock` is reentrant, while the `SemaphoreSlim` is not. So programming with the `lock` is more forgiving. In case there is a rare path in your app where you are acquiring the same lock twice, the `lock` will acquire it successfully, while the `SemaphoreSlim` will deadlock.
2. The `lock` is syntactic sugar around the [`Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor) class. In other words there is language support for the `Monitor` in C#, and there isn't for the `SemaphoreSlim`. So using the `lock` is comparatively more convenient and less verbose.
3. You can write more robust code with the `lock`, because you can add debugging assertions in auxiliary methods that the lock has been [acquired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.isentered): `Debug.Assert(Monitor.IsEntered(_locker));`
4. You can get contention statistics with the [`Monitor.LockContentionCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.lockcontentioncount) property: *"Gets the number of times there was contention when trying to take the monitor's lock."* There are no statistics available for the `SemaphoreSlim` class.
5. The `SemaphoreSlim` is `IDisposable`, so you have to think about when (and whether) to dispose it. Can you [get away without disposing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033416/do-i-need-to-dispose-a-semaphoreslim) it? Are you disposing it prematurely and risk an `ObjectDisposedException`? These are questions that you don't have to answer with the `lock`.
6. The `lock` can survive in the scenario of an aborted thread. It is translated by the C# compiler [like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRiqQLIAUAlLfY/wHlgAKxhgALqQA2EMAGsYUUgF5SAOxgB3bgG4+/BjPmkORhVB50CBm6QAiEAEJmAlmoDmAZXEBXAGZ+uvoGAL7BYdaMAA5QLgBuAIbiMOSsDs6ycm5evgHctKQRIUA=):

```
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockTaken);
        DoBlockingStuff();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(obj);
        }
    }
```

The [`Monitor.Enter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter) has been coded carefully so that in case the thread is aborted, the `lockTaken` will have the correct value. On the contrary the `SemaphoreSlim.Wait` is typically called outside of the `try`/`finally` block, so there is a small window that the current thread can be aborted without releasing the lock, resulting in a deadlock.

The .NET Core/5+ platform has dropped support for the [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) method, so you could rightfully say that the last point has only theoretical value.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is about advantages and not disadvantages, but a lock disadvantage is that it does not work well with async await. That is because the thread might be changed between before and after the await: you are not allowed to enter the lock on one thread and leave it on another. When this happens the lock will throw an exception. SemaphoreSlim does not have this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75781414

When using lock directly with await, the compiler will throw an error when you try to build it. So you should not run into this issue. But when you use Monitor.Enter/Exit instead of lock (lock is syntactic suger for Monitor.Enter/Exit), the compiler will not notice the problem and you may run into it at runtime.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21404261