# Locking behaviour when dealing with async/await

Tags: c#, async-await, locking, task

I might be overthinking this, but I'm not sure I understand how locking works when dealing with await/async.

Given the following, after each `await` a different thread can return to execute the next bit of code, right? (unless being run on a thread with a `TaskScheduler` like WPF)

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    // ThreadPoolWorker 1

    await Something();

    // ThreadPoolWorker 2

    await SomethingElse();

    // ThreadPoolWorker 3

    await SomethingElse2();

    // ThreadPoolWorker 4
});
```

So with that in mind, couldn't I end up with the following issue, where I kick off two tasks using `Task.Run()`. The first task enters the `WaitAsync()` on `Thread1`, and so `Thread1` has the lock, but returns from the `WaitAsync` on another thread, e.g `Thread 2`.

While in the mean time, in the second `Task.Run()`, `Thread 5` entered the `Task.Delay()`, but when it returns from the `await`, could in theory be on `Thread 1`? .. so now will not have to wait for the lock?

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    // Thread 1
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    // Thread 2
    
    ...
});

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    // Thread 5
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    // Thread 1
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

    ...
});
```

I'm guessing the way this is handled is that `await Semaphore.WaitAsync` must always return on the thread that it was invoked on? is this implemented in SemaphoreSlim itself?

Comment: Aren't you also calling `semaphoreSlim.Release()` anywhere? Or you've just removed the releasing to keep the example simple?

Comment: Yes, to keep the code short.

Comment: a semaphore is designed to halt all process to eneter a critical section, so for only on e process to let be passed all other wait till time out hits. so your work is to have all process to be processed in time like the starving philosophers

Comment: I think that adding back the `Release` would add clarity of your question. Currently you are talking about locks, but there is nothing in the code that conveys the intention of [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion). You could also include the code that instantiates the `semaphoreSlim`, so that we can see the value of the `initialCount` parameter and get some insights. Ideally you should post a minimal and reproducible example, that includes actual and expected behavior.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm not trying to show a reproducible example. I'm asking what stops the theoretical case I mentioned occurring. Adding the usual try/finally to release the semaphore does not add anything to the question.

Comment: ​Possible duplicates: [Does SemaphoreSlim (.NET) prevent same thread from entering block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985233/does-semaphoreslim-net-prevent-same-thread-from-entering-block) and also [Lock and SemaphoreSlim usage difference with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944070/lock-and-semaphoreslim-usage-difference-with-async-await).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question would be better with a complete code example that has an output and a specific expectation that is not met.

However, I'll try to answer it how I understand it. So for this code:

```
Task.Run(async () => // Task A
{
    // Thread 1
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    // Thread 2
});

Task.Run(async () => // Task B
{
    // Thread 5
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    // Thread 1
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
});
```

Your fear is that The 2 tasks run concurrently and that Thread 1 Executes the first half of the first task and thus has the Semaphore and can circumvent the second Wait?

That's not what will happen. Keep in mind that the Tasks are commands that shall be executed in order and can be executed by different Threads with another one taking over after every await. However, that also means that the waits are not actually done on any Thread. Think of it like this:

- Thread 1 starts progress on Task A and encounters the await. The Semaphore blocks and the Task is put aside as it cannot execute further at this moment.
- Meanwhile, Thread 5 started progress on Task B and set it aside also as it cannot be executed for the next 5 seconds
- Threadpool idles
- Main thread calls Semaphore.Release()
- Thus, Task A becomes executable and a thread (Thread 2) grabs it and runs it further.
- The timer elapses and Task B becomes eligible again. Thread 1 grab it and continues. With the call to WaitAsync(), the Task needs to be put aside again. This is because the Semaphore knows about its state and it is busy.
- Someone calls Release()
- Task B becomes eligible again and some thread can pick it up

Or to rephrase it, it does not matter which thread starts a WaitAsync() or which one takes over afterwards. What matters is that a release of (a full) Semaphore will cause exactly one task to become executable even if many are waiting on it.

Comment: Thank you. The source of my confusion was also that I was thinking that SemaphoreSlim had thread affinity, when it doesn't. So semaphoreSlim wouldn't have the problem I was thinking of, ... but a Mutex would, as it does have thread affinity