# Techniques for making a method non-reentrant

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core, semaphore

I have an ASP.NET Core application with an `async` method with a signature something like this.

```
public async Task RunAsync()
{
    // ...
}
```

I'm concerned about this method running at the same time by more than one thread.

It looks like I can use `lock` or a `SemaphoreSlim`. Can someone help explain these options in a way that I can choose between the two?

Also, does the fact that my method is `async` impact the decision?

Comment: Not an answer, but be aware that it usually does not matter whether or not the same function is active in more than one thread. What usually matters is whether or not different threads are accessing the same _data._ It's the data that needs protection, not the functions, and the data needs protection even if it is being accessed by _different_ functions in different threads.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Yes, my method creates reports, which are cached, and a block of code will need to decide if the existing cache is still current. That's exactly where I run into trouble if it's being accessed by multiple threads at the same time. The cache logic will be in a static class. And the entire code to create the report must complete before the cache is in a predictable state.

Comment: Related: [Lock and SemaphoreSlim usage difference with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944070/lock-and-semaphoreslim-usage-difference-with-async-await). It seems though that your problem is the cache. It might be better to fix the cache, than fix all the code that uses the cache.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I didn't follow that. I have no idea what you mean by *fix the cache*. How is it the problem? Note that the code that generates the report (and cache) needs to be guarded against being reentrant or else a thread could check the cache while a report is being created.

Comment: A good cache implementation should protect by itself against overlapping executions of the value-factories. Typically this policy is enforced with the [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) class, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once/28340261#28340261) by Yuval Itzchakov.

Answer (score 1):

So, I don't know all the details of how these two methods work, but I found that you cannot use `await` within a `lock`. So even though `lock` appears to have some advantages, in my case, only a `SemaphoreSlim` will work.