# Lock into async Method into my Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

i need to lock a method preventing multiple simultaneous execution,
this is my solutions,
is it thread safe? is it safe?

```
    public async Task ExecuteApiCalls()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
             var t = Task.Run(async () => {
                //my async code  
             }  
             Task.WaitAny(t);
        });

        
        
    }
```

Comment: *Waiting for Stephen C to chime in ...

Comment: I think you should consider [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: This may be interesting, too (read Eric Lippert's answer). https://stackoverflow.com/q/7612602/982149

Comment: Why don't you lock in the very inner function?

Comment: Also: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming - Know Your Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#know-your-tools) : _"Problem: Synchronize access to a shared resource , Solution: SemaphoreSlim"_