# Unable to await in a lock, how do I ensure async variable and method are not accessed from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, semaphore

I have the following code:

```
public const int ThreadLimitMax = 128;
private static object setThreadLimitLock = new object();
private static SemaphoreSlim totalThreadLimiter = new SemaphoreSlim(ThreadLimit, ThreadLimitMax);
        
public static int ThreadLimit { get; private set; } = 128;

public static async Task SetThreadLimit(int max)
{
    if (max > ThreadLimitMax)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(max), $"Cannot have more than {ThreadLimitMax} threads.");
    if (max < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(max), $"Cannot have less than 1 threads.");

    lock (setThreadLimitLock)
    {
        int difference = Math.Abs(ThreadLimit - max);
        if (max < ThreadLimit)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++)
            {
                await totalThreadLimiter.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        else if (max > ThreadLimit)
        {
            totalThreadLimiter.Release(difference);
        }
        ThreadLimit = max;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a method that will modify the amount of available threads in totalThreadLimiter. I keep the maximum number of threads in the ThreadMaxLimit integer.

To change the amount of threads, I need to ensure the ThreadLimit is not accessed until the operation of changing max threads is complete. I also need to ensure that the method is blocked until the totalThreadLimiter has completed with all WaitAsync() calls.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use a lock which supports `await`, such as `SemaphoreSlim` (which has a `WaitAsync` method, and also supports being unlocked on a different thread to the one which locked it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lock` is a helper API around `Monitor`, which is a thread-bound synchronization primitive, which means it isn't suitable for use with `await`, because there is no guarantee what thread you'll be on when you come *back* from an incomplete asynchronous operation.

Ultimately, you need an async-aware synchronization primitive; the most readily available would be `SemaphoreSlim`, which has the `WaitAsync()` API that you would use to acquire the lock, with a `try`/`finally` that calls `Release()`.

In the code in the question, depending on the code branch you either acquire (only) the semaphore, or release the semaphore; that is almost certainly wrong. Correct usage would be something more like:

```cs
await totalThreadLimiter.WaitAsync();
try
{
    // some code with "await" here
}
finally
{
    totalThreadLimiter.Release();
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you! Now I understand user1639030's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement , it wasn't clear to me that the SemaphoreSlim does not suffer from the same issue as lock.

Comment: It would be useful to show the initialization of the semaphore, as the parameters are not obvious.