# "Cannot await in the body of a lock statement" in .NET Core view with asp-* helper tags

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, locking

We are using .NET Core 3.1 with MVC architecture. We have a simple view (`Index.cshtml` file) which renders a list of **in-memory** items returned from the **singleton service**. This is why we need locking mechanism - one thread can add items to the list while they are still being looped over with `foreach` in `Index.cshtml`. If this occurs, the exception `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` is thrown.

**Index.cshtml**

```cs
@{
    var lockObj = new object();
    var collection = Enumerable.Range(1, 10); // returned from the singleton service
}

@lock (lockObj)
{
    @foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@item">
            @item
        </a>
    }
}
```

I am aware that code above doesn't make any sense (`lockObj` needs to be shared among all application layers, it shouldn't be initialized in the view), but it clearly reproduces the build error that I get. Once I build the solution, compiler throws the following error:

```
CS1996 Cannot await in the body of a lock statement
```

If I remove `asp-*` tag helpers, the code compiles successfully. What am I doing wrong? Do `asp-*` tag helpers use `async` methods under the hood? Can I use `asp-*` tag helpers inside `lock` statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use the 'await' operator within the body of a lock statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement)

Comment: @pfx I understand that I can't use `await` operator inside the body of the `lock` statement. However, I am not using any `await` operator **explicitly** in my code. If it is used, it must be used behind-the-scenes by `asp-*` tag helpers.

Comment: Why do you want to lock the html part anyways?

Comment: Depending on the size of your list, copying it with a call to `ToList()` might be the easiest way. No need to lock a collection that will only exist for your view.

Comment: @kingrazer I explained why I want to do that in the question. Singleton service `TestService` maintains an in-memory list of objects (`TestList`). It mutates `TestList` by adding and deleting entries. This same in-memory `TestList` is used in `Index.cshtml`. It can happen that while I am in the middle of looping through the list in `Index.cshtml`, an item gets added to the `TestList` by `TestService`. If this occurs while loop in view is still in progress, an exception is thrown (`Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute`).

Comment: Would you be able to add the lock block inside the singleton service? Or could you use a thread-safe collection?

Comment: I'm guessing the serializer for the asp markup is using some version of `Response.WriteAsync` under the covers. To solve your problem I would create a copy of the mutable data in the controller (within a `lock` block) and pass the copy to the view in the model.

Answer (score 1):

> Do asp-* tag helpers use async methods under the hood?

Possibly.

> Can I use asp-* tag helpers inside lock statement?

No.

> What am I doing wrong?

You don't want to use `lock` here - or anywhere where there could be asynchronous code. In ASP.NET Core, this includes a lot of subcomponents; in ASP.NET pre-core, child actions and similar sub-components *must* be invoked synchronously, and ASP.NET Core fixed that.

For a proper solution, I would recommend using a concurrent or immutable collection. These generally have "snapshot" semantics, so your view code can iterate over the items without blocking any updates. But if you prefer, you can just use `SemaphoreSlim` instead of `lock` for an async-friendly lock.