# WP7 slider drag end event

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, slider, drag

I'm developing a WP7 music player. I use the slider to track the playing progress.
I want to allow user to drag the slider to seek a certain posion within the track, but find no drag end event?

The `slider_ValueChanged` event doesnot satisfy my need.

I follow the instruction here [WPF: Slider with an event that triggers after a user drags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723502/wpf-slider-with-an-event-that-triggers-after-a-user-drags) but it doesnot work on WP7

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow the instruction [here](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2010/06/Basic-Manipulation-Event-Handling-in-Windows-Phone-7.html) using Manipulation Completed Event, and it works