# Has the user changed the value through the UI, or was it changed by the dependency property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a slider that has it's **value** property tied to a dependency property. I need to know if the user has changed the value through the GUI. Unfortunately, the value of this slider is often changed via code and the "Value_Changed" event fires when that happens.

I know of two ways to go around this:

1. Create a boolean and change it to true each time in the code before changing the value, changing it to false afterwards, and then checking for this boolean in the Value_Changed event.
2. Wiring up keypress, click and dragstop events to the slider.

I'm just wondering if there's a better way to know if the user has changed the value via the UI?

Comment: What about the mousedown and keydown events? Both events should occure when the user is doing something either by mouse or keyboard.

Comment: You may check if the slider has focus. If it does, then the value is being changed from the UI. But this would depend on what exactly happens to make the slider change from code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
public bool PositionModifiedByUser
{ /* implement IPropertyChanged if need to bind to this property */ }

// use this property from code
public double Position
{
    get { return m_position ; }
    set { SetPropertyValue ("PositionUI", ref m_position, value) ;
          PositionModifiedByUser = false ; }
}

// bind to this property from the UI
public double PositionUI
{
    get { return m_position ; }
    set { if (SetPropertyValue ("PositionUI", ref m_position, value))
          PositionModifiedByUser = true ; }
}
```

SetPropertyValue is a helper that checks for equality and fires property change notifications if the value actually changes.

Comment: The problem is, when the control is initialized with an initial value, the PositionUI still calls value changed for me.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what scenario you are referring to. Who initializes the control? what initial value? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly duplicate questions. Quick answer:

```
<Slider Thumb.DragCompleted="MySlider_DragCompleted" />
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723502/wpf-slider-with-an-event-that-triggers-after-a-user-drags)

Comment: I've seen that, see point 2. From answer: "Unfortunately, this is only fired when dragging, so you'll need to handle other clicks and key presses separately."

Comment: You don't want to handle KeyPress?

Answer (score 0):

But the answer from Anton is better +1

```
[BindableAttribute(true)]
public double Slider1Value
{
    get { return slider1Value; }
    set
    {
        // only bind to the UI so any call to here came from the UI
        if (slider1Value == value) return;
        // do what you were going to do in value changed here
        slider1Value = value;
    }
}

private void clickHalf(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // manipulate the private varible so set is not called
    slider1Value = slider1Value / 2;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Slider1Value");
}
```