# Why can i use Thumb.DragStarted in other controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hey I found nice solution for  slider on stackoverflow:
[WPF: Slider with an event that triggers after a user drags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723502/wpf-slider-with-an-event-that-triggers-after-a-user-drags/1665843#1665843)

The problem is I don't understand why you can use Thumb.DragStarted or Thumb.DragEntered inside a Slider (any control) that has no co-relation with each other?

Is that because Thumb.DragStarted event is implemented that way that it doesn't matter for it what will invoke that function?

Comment: Closed. See the accepted answer about `RoutedEvents` in the duplicated question, and also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But i know Routed Events. In MSDN you have example of Button.Click routed event placed in stackpanel control. But that StackPanel is inside Button. How it is possible that I can invoke Thumb inside Slider, are there any coleration between Slider and Thumb?

Comment: the Slider contains a `Thumb`. See the [Default Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278073(v=vs.95).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: very useful link, I didn't know MSDN is describing default template of each control - thanks!