# Get WPF Slider value after dragging

Tags: c#, wpf, events, slider

I'm trying to get WPF Slider value after the user finishing to drag the thumb or clicking to move to specific point.

i want to save the new value in db by listening to some kind of event. how can i do this?

i tried the solutions on this question but i end up with nothing - 
[WPF: Slider with an event that triggers after a user drags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723502/wpf-slider-with-an-event-that-triggers-after-a-user-drags)

each time it enters the event lots of times

thanks.

xaml:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding VoipVolume}" MouseLeftButtonUp="slider_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
```

codebehind:

```
public double VoipVolume
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VoipVolumeProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(VoipVolumeProperty, value);
            VolumeChanged(value);
        }
    }

private void VolumeChanged(object value)
    {
        StationViewModel viewModel = this.DataContext as StationViewModel;

        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            if (end)
            {
                viewModel.OnVolumeChange((float)VoipVolume);
                end = false;
            }
        }
    }
    bool end = false;


    private void slider_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        end = true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Possibly duplicate. hope this may help you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/723547/1611490

Comment: Code added.  Ishan Pandya i wrote that i tried this soultions.

Comment: {Binding VoipVolume} won't work. You are in the xaml.cs file right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't have a choice, in the end we use TickFrequency because we need to save the changes in the slider to db, and we don't want it to happen for every 0.001..

thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly duplicate. hope this may help you out: stackoverflow.com/a/723547/1611490

```
 <Slider Thumb.DragCompleted="MySlider_DragCompleted" />
```

and under MySlider_DragCompleted event, update your property of the VM or get the value.

Comment: "Code added. Ishan Pandya i wrote that i tried this soultions. "
He even said in comments he tried that solution.

Comment: @Dominik :- I was late to post it as answer brother.

Answer (score 0):

if your are using FW 4.5 or above, try using the "Dalay" property.

http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/21/wpf-4-5-part-4-the-new-bindings-delay-property/