# Change the value of Slider by dragging the Slider and Clicking button have different trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have three Controls:a slider, a button, and a textbox.
And what I want to achieve is that When I drag the slider to change it's value,the content of textbox changes.The content of textbox is the value of the slider.However, when I click the button, the value of the slider adds 1 but the content of textbox doesn't change.The textbox shows the value of the Slider.But it changes it's content only when I change the value of slider by dragging the slider.
So how can I make this work in code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723502/wpf-slider-with-an-event-that-triggers-after-a-user-drags) is where I found the solution.

And my code is:
In Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Slider Name="mySlider" ValueChanged="mySlider_ValueChanged" Thumb.DragStarted ="mySlider_DragStarted"
            Thumb.DragCompleted ="mySlider_DragCompleted"/>
    <TextBox Name="tboxValue" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="0"
             Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Add" Name="btnAdd" Click="btnAdd_Click" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

In code:

```
private bool isdragging = false;

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mySlider.Value += 1;
    }

    private void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (isdragging)
            tboxValue.Text = mySlider.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void mySlider_DragStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        isdragging = true;
    }

    private void mySlider_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        isdragging = false;
    }
```

It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the textbox TEXT property to the slider's VALUE property using Element Name

```
 <Slider x:Name="Slider"></Slider>
 <TextBox x:Name="SliderValue" Text="{Binding ElementName=Slider, Path=Value}"></TextBox>
```

The textbox will auto update when the slider value change.

Comment: when I click the 'Add' button , the value of slider adds 1 but the content of textbox can't change.